# Fill nan values with color that corresponds to next column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, nan

I want to fill the nan values with the color type corresponding to that condition. for example, if it is brown and condition have nan value the nan should be filled with 2.0[dataset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulxSX.png)

> Blockquote

```
condition   color_type  length(m)   height(cm)  X1  X2  duration
0   2.0 Brown Tabby 0.80    7.78    13  9   73
1   1.0 White   0.72    14.19   13  9   1862
2   NaN Brown   0.15    40.90   15  4   752
3   1.0 White   0.62    17.82   0   1   755
4   2.0 Black   0.50    11.06   18  4   52
```

Comment: Maybe you should try the Pandas documentation first. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html . Then, you can show us what and how you're trying to solve this with your code and then we can help you! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask:

```
cond = df['color_type'] == 'Brown'
df.loc[cond, "condition"] = df.loc[cond, "condition"].fillna(2.0)
```

---

For many colors, you can do:

```
cond = df['color_type'].isin(your_list_of_colors)
```

Comment: yes this works but there are 50 different colors almost.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this
df["condition"]=df["condition"].fillna(df.groupby("color_type")["condition"].transform(lambda x:x.mode()[0]))
This should solve your problem

Comment: I am trying to solve but its showing index out of bounds error

Comment: I ran this code on your given dataframe and it's working properly , if you can show screenshot of error I can help more